# SQL query help: Calculate max of previous rows in the same query

Tags: postgresql

I want to find for each row(where B = C = D = 1), the max of A among its previous rows(where B = C = D = 1) excluding its row after its ordered in chronological order.

Data in table looks like this:

```
+-------+-----+-----+-----+------+------+
|Grp id |  B  |  C  |  D  |  A   | time |
+-------+---- +-----+-----+------+------+
|  111  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  52  | t    | 
|  111  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  33  | t+1  | 
|  111  |  0  |  1  |  0  |  34  | t+2  | 
|  111  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  22  | t+3  | 
|  111  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  12  | t+4  | 
|  222  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  16  | t    | 
|  222  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  18  | t2+1 | 
|  222  |  1  |  1  |  0  |  13  | t2+2 | 
|  222  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  12  | t2+3 | 
|  222  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  09  | t2+4 | 
|  222  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  22  | t2+5 | 
|  222  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  19  | t2+6 | 
+-------+-----+-----+-----+------+------+
```

Above table is resultant of below query. Its obtained after left joins as below. Joins are necessary according to my project requirement.

```
SELECT  Grp id, B, C, D, A, time, xxx
FROM "DCR" dcr 
    LEFT JOIN "DCM" dcm ON "Id" = dcm."DCRID"
    LEFT JOIN "DC" dc ON dc."Id" = dcm."DCID" 
ORDER BY dcr."time"
```

Result column needs to be evaluated based on formula I mentioned above. It needs to be calculated in same pass as we need to consider only its previous rows. Above xxx needs to be replaced by a subquery/statement to obtain the result.

And the result table should look like this:

```
+-------+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+
|Grp id |  B  |  C  |  D  |  A   | time |Result|  
+-------+---- +-----+-----+------+------+------+
|  111  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  52  | t    |  -   | 
|  111  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  33  | t+1  |  -   |
|  111  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  34  | t+2  |  33  |
|  111  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  22  | t+3  |  34  |
|  111  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  12  | t+4  |  -   |
|  222  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  16  | t    |  -   |
|  222  |  1  |  0  |  0  |  18  | t2+1 |  -   |
|  222  |  1  |  1  |  0  |  13  | t2+2 |  -   |
|  222  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  12  | t2+3 |  16  |
|  222  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  09  | t2+4 |  16  |
|  222  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  22  | t2+5 |  16  |
|  222  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  19  | t2+6 |  22  |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The column could be computed with a window function:

```
CASE WHEN b = 1 AND c = 1 AND d = 1
     THEN max(a) FILTER (WHERE b = 1 AND c = 1 AND d = 1)
                 OVER (PARTITION BY "grp id"
                       ORDER BY time
                       ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
     ELSE NULL
END
```

I didn't test it.